# How to get the final submission URL for a HTML form programmatically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, query-string

I have a simple HTML form which uses GET instead of POST.

```
<form id="form" action="https://www.example.com/search" method="GET">
    <input name="foo" type="text" />
    <input name="bar" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

When the user hits 'Submit', I'd expect them to be directed to an URL like `http://www.example.com/search?foo=abc&bar=123`, i.e. the action URL with a query string appended.

Is there an easy way to get this final form URL with query parameters programmatically in Javascript, without having to construct it? Something like `document.getElementById('form').submissionURL`

Comment: No, there isn't. You're after something like jQuery's [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which is [actually relatively complicated to implement](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js).

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. I thought there might be something available since the browser needs to construct this URL at some point anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Using Jquery serialize you should be able to get this done

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var submitURL=$( '#form' ).attr( 'action' );
  if(submitURL.indexOf("?")==-1)
  {
  console.log( submitURL+'?'+$( '#form' ).serialize() );
  }
  else
  {
  console.log( submitURL+'&'+$( '#form' ).serialize() );
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zrypfens/1/

Comment: This will fail if the URL in the action attribute has a query string

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:javascript] which says (on the [tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): *Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.*